# A type for sorted arrays in Swift

Tags: swift, types

Not sure if this is science fiction, but would it be possible to create a `type` that represents an `Array` that matches a certain condition, such as being always sorted?

Or a `2-tuple` where the first element is always bigger than the second?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're describing is called a dependent type (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependent_type). Swift does not have these, and I'm not aware of any mainstream (non-research) language that does. You can of course create a special kind of collection that is indexed like an array and sorts itself whenever it is modified, and you can crate a struct with `greater` and `lessor` properties that always reorders itself. But these criteria cannot be attached to the existing Array or tuple types.